# How to collect only the required integers from a string by matching specific word in python

Tags: python, string, url

Suppose i had the following string

```
str = 'http://www.example.com/servlet/av/jd?ai=782&ji=2553120&sn=I'
```

I want to get only the integer number for `ji` that is `255312` becasue there may be different number generating for `ji` in the above url

Thanks in advance......

Comment: There are several ji parameters in the URL? Please update the example. BTW 255312 is not in the URL. The zero is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parse the URL with [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/servlet/av/jd?ai=782&ji=2553120&sn=I'
>>> query_string = urlparse.urlparse(url).query
>>> query_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(query_string)
>>> query_dict
{'ai': ['782'], 'ji': ['2553120'], 'sn': ['I']}
>>> int(query_dict['ji'])
2553120
```

Now you can easily retrieve the desired values.

Comment: i want to get the value of only ji that is 2553120 by using regular expressions or something(only the value of ji)

Comment: becuase in url above the value will be changing fdrquently so i am going to use that ji value for some other purpose

Comment: @shivakrishna: Except for the "regular expression" part, I already know this.  Using a regular expression here has lots of disadvantages and no advantages.  Why do you wan to use one?

Comment: @shivakrishna so use `urlparse.parse_qs(query_string)['ji']` to get a list of them